# Do I need to change to Redis Cache in Azure from Nov 30 2016?

Tags: asp.net, azure, session, caching

I have a single instance of a website hosted in Azure, which uses the in-role session cache. This uses some very basic calls to pass data between pages, such as `Session("MustChangePassword") = "True"`

Microsoft have emailed Azure customers saying that the in-role and managed caches are going to be retired, and that Azure Redis cache should be used instead:

> Azure Managed Cache Service and Azure In-Role Cache to be retired November 30, 2016 
>   As a reminder, Azure Managed Cache Service and Azure In-Role Cache service will remain available for existing customers until November 30, 2016. After this date, Managed Cache Service will be shut down, and In-Role Cache service will no longer be supported. We recommend that you migrate to Azure Redis Cache. For more information on migrating, please visit the [Migrate from Managed Cache Service to Azure Redis Cache](https://click.email.microsoftemail.com/?qs=7a5a002bab3d3740c33d24b8abd1579b216319a1b942b9918949bb9e02004211e4be0bcd1d2db4c4d754a9f2c55e6358) documentation webpage. For more information about the retirement, please visit the [Azure Blog](https://click.email.microsoftemail.com/?qs=7a5a002bab3d37400d9ebe20649ecdc029d29bfa663f71d74f00d611d886b5814083dfd9707ce9621bbc300a11452d48).

Is this going to still affect cloud services that use just one instance, or will Session data just completely break after this change is made if I don't do anything?

If I do have to change to Redis cache, I see from the supplied links that I can download it as a NuGet package and make changes to the `web.config` file. However, I am then unsure as to whether I'd need to make changes to the code, or whether the calls to `Session("Whatever")` would still work without any further changes needed.

So in summary:
1) Do I need to change to the new cache?
2) If so, what code changes do I need to make over and above configuring the new cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that using a session call such as `Session("MustChangePassword") = "True"` is absolutely fine to still use in the case of running a single instance machine.

It may not be supported, but it still works, and I have not had to add any other kind of session management to this project.

Everything is working exactly as it was before the announcement, and continues to work after the deadline had passed.

> So in summary:
>
> 1) Do I need to change to the new cache?
>
> 2) If so, what code changes do I need to make over and above configuring the new cache?

The answers to the above questions were 1) No, and 2) No changes needed.

Answer (score 0):

This announcement is at least one year old, if not older.

> So in summary:
>
> 1. Do I need to change to the new cache?
> 2. If so, what code changes do I need to make over and above configuring the new cache?

To Anser your questions:

1. YES
2. Check out the documentation links you quoted.

And by the way, you cannot downlaod Azure Redis Cache as a NuGet package. What you download is Client SDK/API to work with Azure Redis Cache. Azure Redis Cache is a [separate service in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/). Which is also [billed separately](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cache/).

Comment: I don't think we would need to switch by 30th November. Eventually yes though. My understanding is that the SDKs released after 30th November will not have support for this. But I am guessing that we can continue to use this with older SDKs even after 30th November.